# AWS S3 - 20.000 requests in 3 days? Is it normal in a real-time app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I just started using AWS less than a week ago and my free tier usage is already gone.

I do not know why... I use Amplify for flutter, and I don't have any intensive tasks in my project.

I see in the "Top AWS Free Tier services table" that "Amazon Simple Storage Service" has had +20.000 requests! I understand that that would be possible with an infinite loop of some sort, but I believe I haven't created any...

I am using observeQuery ( https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/real-time/q/platform/flutter/  ) to build a real-time app. I expected it to require more requests than manually querying but not that many in just a few days with just 2 testers.

Am I missing something?

How many requests does real-time querying do/require?

This is my current billing:
[image: Service charges]

This is the status of my free tier right now:
[image: Free tier usage]

Comment: The Amazon S3 pricing for **GET, SELECT, and all other requests** is `$0.0004 per 1000 requests`. Thus, you have been charged 1c because they couldn't charge a fraction of 1c.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. What was weird were those +20,000 requests in just 3 days... I didn't do them... that's why I was worried. But apparently it is normal for new projects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been clarified here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/discussions/1435#discussioncomment-2301266

These requests are normal if this is a new project. But you should not expect to see them every month, they are a one-time thing.